# Why do properties require explicit typing during compilation?

Tags: objective-c, properties

Compilation using property syntax requires the type of the receiver to be known at compile time. I may not understand something, but this seems like a broken or incomplete compiler implementation considering that Objective-C is a dynamic language.

The property "comment" is defined with:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *comment;
```

and synthesized with:

```
@synthesize comment;
```

"document" is an instance of one of several classes which conform to:

```
@protocol DocumentComment <NSObject>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *comment;

@end
```

and is simply declared as:

```
id document;
```

When using the following property syntax:

```
stringObject = document.comment;
```

the following error is generated by gcc:

```
error: request for member 'comment' in something not a structure or union
```

However, the following equivalent receiver-method syntax, compiles without warning or error and works fine, as expected, at run-time:

```
stringObject = [document comment];
```

I don't understand why properties require the type of the receiver to be known at compile time. Is there something I am missing? I simply use the latter syntax to avoid the error in situations where the receiving object has a dynamic type. Properties seem half-baked.

Answer (score 4):

Compiling property access requires knowing how to translate the property name into the correct getter/setter name. Without knowing the type of the receiver, the compiler cannot possibly know what the getter/setter is called, as the property may have overridden the name as part of its declaration, like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, getter=myComment) NSString *comment;
```

If the compiler were to go ahead and generate code for your untyped example, it would generate `[document comment]`, which will fail at runtime as the correct generated code is actually `[document myComment]`.

Comment: But at runtime it doesn't know the actual type of document either but it still succeeds using standard receiver-method syntax.  This is a dynamic language.  Of course properties document.comment will fail with the property declaration you provide, which makes perfect sense.  The compiler has the same lack of information in the receiver-method syntax example, but the compiler let's it go.  You can use a non-existant method name and the compiler will also let it go.

Comment: The compile will only accept `[document comment]` without complaint if it knows that there exists, somewhere, a method named -comment on an object. If you were to type `[document sdlkjf]` you will instead get a warning. But you are correct, methods use dynamic dispatch and will only fail at runtime if the object doesn't actually handle that message. On the other hand, properties are a compile-time feature, and property access is therefore resolved at compile-time.

Comment: ... and if the there were three `comment` methods, one that returned `NSString*`, one `char*` and one returning a structure, all dynamism is out the window anyway.  The reality is that Objective-C very much is a statically typed language without that static typing getting in the way of either dynamic dispatch or polymorphism.

Comment: @bbum  Properties do NOT support polymorphism -- and polymorphism is precisely the feature I am discussing here.  I don't think you folks have provided a valid reason for the limitation yet (but an earnest thanks for the input) beyond a questionable philosophical safety net against "ambiquities" which is the crux of the benefit of polymorphism.

Comment: @kevin property synthesized methods are compiled just as traditional methods -- are you making a claim that they are different?  From my understanding they use the same method lookup mechanism in the runtime; there hasn't been a reason mentioned besides the imposition of a static typing philosophy, why they have been designed to function in a manner asymmetric to receiver-method syntax.  The compiler could simply throw a warning if there is an ambiguity or if the method name could not be found -- instead the compiler throws an error as if the design committee knew better than you.

Comment: It's not a matter of ambiguity. It's a simple matter that, without an explicit type that can be used to resolve the property, the compiler *cannot* know what the appropriate method to call is. At compile-time, `document.comment` will get translated into `[document comment]` **iff** the property `comment` is declared to have the getter `-comment`. Without the explicit type and property information, the compiler cannot safely emit a call to `[document comment]`

Answer (score 3):

Kevin nailed one of the symptoms.

When designing properties, the very specific decision was made *not* to support `id` as the target of dot syntax.   Beyond the ambiguities that Kevin points out, the desire to avoid **all** ambiguities related to (id) receivers was considered desirable.

In general, the use of fully unqualified `id` is both undesirable and actively discouraged.  In creating new features in the language, not supporting `id` discourages the proliferation fragile coding patterns across the new feature(s).

Comment: I disagree.  It adds an asymmetric static typed feature.  It defeats, at least syntactically, a useful dynamic feature of the language when using properties.  I wonder what the original Stepstone architects would say about this.  Some might have fought against properties entirely.  I like their convenience but the asymmetry is frustrating in several specific situations. Protocols can be used to eliminate the so called "fragile coding patterns" you mention.

Comment: Static typing is not a bad thing. I think Obj-C strikes a fairly good balance between dynamic typing and static typing, with some features being more dynamic than others. Properties are pretty much a compile-time feature (the only influence on the runtime I can think of is the metadata is available through runtime methods) and, as such, fall into the static typing side of things.

Comment: Brad Cox actually likes the direction the language has taken.  I understand where your criticism, but don't see it as being applicable to a large enough extent to warrant incurring the fragility implied by fully dynamic typing.  Quite a while ago -- 1996ish, or so IIRC -- the decision was made to move away from generic typing as much as possible.  Note that if you have specific problematic patterns, please do file a bug or ask an SO question!

Comment: I read Brad Cox's book almost 20 years ago. I know a man can change in that time, but he isn't the man he used to be if he thinks that "unqualified id is ... actively discouraged" in all situations.  In my current project I only have a few places where I need an unqualified id, and it is to support legitimate polymorphism.  But if I see properties as static as you suggest, though a property synthesized method can be used dynamically without issue, and use receiver-method syntax, it is a fair compromise - but the type casting often required is annoying.  There is a better compromise.

Comment: There is a difference between absolute polymorphism and partial polymorphism.  The former is `id`;  it can be a reference to anything.  Whereas the latter is something like `NSView*` w/the implied subclasses being valid, too, or adding protocols to `id` or, more practically, `NSObject*`.  It isn't that pure/absolute polymorphism is useless -- it has its uses -- but those uses are pretty darned rare and the # of problems it incurs are quite common.  In designing @property, a goal was to guide devs to a naturally less fragile realization of their applications w/o sacrificing all dynamism.

Comment: I can certainly change my polymorphic instance variables to NSObject *, but it doesn't solve the asymmetric syntax interpretation.  And I did specify a protocol in my original example -- it can be a useful runtime type checking mechanism -- but it doesn't effect properties at compile time.  I can understand the paternalism guiding the design of properties as this is Apple we are talking about -- it is unfortunate that developers are treated in a similar vein as users in their eyes.

Comment: Having authored Objective-C for 20+ years, including teaching many classes, I haven't seen a compelling use of full polymorphism that isn't hamstrung by the static typing realities of C.  However, I also don't claim to have seen everything.  Show some code in a new question or add an example to this one, please?

Comment: @ctpenrose For the record, Obj-C protocols can declare properties.

Comment: @Kevin  I declared a property within a protocol in my original question.  Not sure why you are stating this here.